# Incomplete Type Inference in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code, which leads to a type error `TS2322` at the commented position:

```
interface Environment<Position, Result, Results> {
    listResults(results : Results) : Iterable<[Position, Iterable<Result>]>
}

function* flatListResults<E extends Environment<P, R, Rs>, P, R, Rs>(
    env : E, results : Rs) : Iterable<[P, R]>
{
    for (const [p, rs] of env.listResults(results)) {
        for (const r of rs) {
            yield [p, r];
        }
    }
}

function test(env : Environment<number, string, [number, string[]]>, results : [number, string[]]) {
    for (const [p, rs] of env.listResults(results)) {
        let q : number = p // type checks successfully
    }
    for (const [p, r] of flatListResults(env, results)) {
        let q : number = p // yields error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'
    }
}
```

I would consider this type error a bug. Would you agree?

Comment: Sure, I am gonna make 2 questions out of it.

Comment: So to be clear, the question is *not* "how do I write this so it works", but "do we agree that the error is a bug in TypeScript"?

Comment: If so, the answer is that it is not a bug, but possibly a missing feature as requested in [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234).  Generic constraints are not used as inference sites, so `P` and `R` cannot be inferred from anything as they are not mentioned in the types of the function parameters. The "correct" way to write this is to make sure that good inference sites for all type parameters exist in the function params, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NB8aDW) (it's not clear why you needed `E` at all there).  But that's out of scope for the question as asked.

Comment: ^ Does that fully address your question?  If so I'll write up an answer post explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it does address my question fully. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I'll write up the answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not considered a TypeScript bug; instead, it's more of a missing feature.

---

The problem with a call signature like

```
declare function flatListResults<E extends Environment<P, R, Rs>, P, R, Rs>(
  env: E, results: Rs): Iterable<[P, R]>;
```

is that there are no *inference sites* for the `P` or `R` type parameters.  The `env` and `results` parameters are of types `E` and `Rs`, respectively, so when you call the function the compiler can infer `E` from the type of the `env` argument and `Rs` from the type of the `results` argument. But there is *nowhere* for the compiler to infer `P` and `R`.

You might object that the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `E` should provide the needed information: since `E extends Environment<P, R, Rs>`, couldn't the compiler use the inferred type of `E` and the constraint to infer `P` and `R`?  Maybe, but such a feature was never implemented; generic constraints are *not* considered inferences sites.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234), a bug report that was re-classified as a feature request (so it's officially Not A Bug), and that was eventually closed as not planned.

---

According to that issue, if you find yourself needing this, you should use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) instead so that the constraint information appears explicitly in the function parameter types:

```
declare function flatListResults<E extends Environment<P, R, Rs>, P, R, Rs>(
  env: E & Environment<P, R, Rs>, results: Rs): Iterable<[P, R]>;
```

Now `env` can be used to infer `P` and `R` as well as `E`m and inference works as desired:

```
for (const [p, r] of flatListResultsBetter(env, results)) {
  let q: number = p // okay
}
```

Of course that refactoring presumes you actually need `E` in your type to begin with.  If `E` was just supposed to be a vehicle for inferring `P` and `R` (which it can't do) then you could just dispense with `E` entirely and write `env` in terms of `P`, `R`, and `Rs`:

```
declare function flatListResults<P, R, Rs>(
  env: Environment<P, R, Rs>, results: Rs
): Iterable<[P, R]>;
```

Inference also works here, and you're not carrying around an extra type parameter. And so this is how I would give your function its call signature, at least given the information in the example.

[Playground like to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgG7CgexAWwnAB4AFHAZ2DGDwBpkAlCCgVwBswHm3OKA+ZAG8AUMmTtgFMDw5gKACigs5FAFxMVfAJQaAkpChwARuwjEA2uSo16yA9BNniszvwC6-EQF8RfgCYQCOxwysgwrCAItiDhIWAAMlIyWvIAQnD+xKjIEAAekCD+FGiY2HiEJKTc3AIM1Uy1-ApiuZgaqAzKvPIajBS69oZO5lbcngDcfiKBwaEoEVExcXCJya7pEGCG2bkFRMWlWLgERGBkNUx1yA2MTS3iRBgdyABkR+WnVZf9-F2p6iugwcRlMo1ukwCQRCYUW0VosRg8SS0g2FAujSuzVaTw6ZROlXOtya-x6gP6ImBwzBlgh-Cmfjhy0g0gUuI+BLOxBArHwxmgDGkUFAAHMGBYeXyBcghaKLO5PKTVBoJbz+VBBWBhSARfL3NphH5xDAcFBkAoEHhpMgLAAHLruZA4GArNaogEZfxszBKnQG0TicRmMDIACOGkl6uQAF5kLbkAB6BO5KC4KCtXzG03my0ga12h1Ol1I1YolJktJbQzejC++Taf2tINbMMRtXQGNxxPJnAAazgAE8M60TWaLVaQwXkFBHc7XWW0TW6wNG4GJC3w8hIx3Y-Gk07exAB-4+0fh94gA)